# specifying levels from table in pgfplots' contour gnuplot

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

Is it possible to specify contour levels from table in the following code?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        title={$x \exp(-x^2-y^2)$},
        domain=-2:2,
        enlargelimits,
        view={0}{90}]
            \addplot3[gnuplot={levels={-0.1,-0.2,-0.6}},thick] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `contour gnuplot={levels={-0.1,-0.2,-0.4}}`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        title={$x \exp(-x^2-y^2)$},
        domain=-2:2,
        enlargelimits,
        view={0}{90}]
            \addplot3[contour gnuplot={levels={-0.1,-0.2,-0.4}},thick] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`-0.6` is too small to be shown.

Comment: Maybe the question is not clear. The specific function I plotted is of no importance. I'm interested in giveing levels from table. It's easy to give inline levels when they are only a few (three in this case). But what if I want to give a high number of levels? `levels={-0.4,-0.39,...,-0.1}` doesn't work, for example.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis: That list is processed by gnuplot so I have not much idea. I think you have to give all levels by yourself.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Why don't you use `contour gnuplot={number=14},` so that the number of levels are specified.?

Comment: Because they'd be equispaced, whereas I need them not to be so.
Actually I produce them joining more equistaced lists, so I would like to write something like `levels={{0,1,...,10},{10.1,10.2,...,11.5}}`